# Интересует почему не работает space-between . в блоке card__inner

Tags: flexbox

Желтая кнопка при разрешении mobile, должна отодвинуться влево

```css
.card__inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="card__inner">
  <div class="card__inner__wrapper">
    <p class="card__inner__price-new">900₽</p>
    <p class="card__inner__price-jetty">1200 р на причале</p>
  </div>
  <button class="card__inner__button">Подробнее</button>
</div>
```

Ссылка на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1db3w9cp/)

Answer (score 0):

Ругался Flex - старшего родителя.
убрал - все заработало!